# No text shown at NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have two view controllers and I want to store the "name" entered in the second and to be shown in the first one. I already made it work that a value is stored, and now I want to store the name entered by the user.

So here's the code of the view controller where the name should be shown:

```
import UIKit

var name = [String]()

class profile: UIViewController {

//Name
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UILabel!

var vornameLabel = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Name
    nameTextField.text = "\(name)"

    //Vorname speichern
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(name, forKey: "vorname")

    name = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("vorname") as! [String]

}
```

And this is the code of second view controller where the "name" is entered:

```
import UIKit

class profileSettings: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var vornameLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var nachnameLabel: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func addInformation(sender: AnyObject) {

        vornameLabel.text = "\(name)"

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(name, forKey: "vorname")

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        //in Profil
        var destProfile:profile = segue.destinationViewController as! profile

        destProfile.vornameLabel = vornameLabel.text
        destProfile.nachnameLabel = nachnameLabel.text

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If the user is entering their name and that is going into vornameLabel successfully then in addInformation() you are overwriting what ever the user entered into vornameLable with "(name)" so you have now lost what the user entered.

2) name  is not being set to anything (unless you have that in another part of your code that you have not shown)

3) So 1 and 2 together means vornameLable contains nothing.

4) Even if vornameLable did contain something, then in viewDidLoad() you are calling setObject which will overwrite any value that was stored to NSUserDefaults with whatever is in name.

I think you need to show more code, this can't be all of it.If it is then it not doing anything.

Updated after receiving info the posted code is all there is:

a) name doesn't contain anything, therefore you are not saving anything to defaults. Change it to var name = "My name".

b) Change vornameLabel.text = "(name)" tp vornameLabel.text = name

c) change NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(name, forKey: "vorname") to NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(vornameLable.text, forKey: "vorname")

d) remove NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(name, forKey: "vorname") in viewDidLoad

Comment: actually it is all for these two view controllers. Well, I'm just at the beginning of my app and think this is an essential part so I wanted to do that first

Comment: I've updated the answer. I know you are new, but what were you expecting to happen? name doesn't contain anything, it is empty, it contains nothing, therefore there is nothing to store.

Comment: Alright works so far! But it doesn't update when the app is opened again, the value is still entered but not shown at the launch of the app

Comment: try calling synchronize() on the defaults when you store the value. If it doesn't work, then post a new question with all of your new code describing the new problem.

Comment: synchronize doesn't help. would viewdidappear or viewwillappear help?

Comment: You'll need to post you most recent code so we can see what you have now there has been changes made.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, set your values in viewWillAppear:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
{
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    name = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("vorname") as! [String]
    nameTextField.text = "\(name)"
}
```